# Set a value for a DWORD32 value in the registry only if it already exists | PowerShell

Tags: powershell, registry

I want to set a value for DWORD32 value in the registry only if it already exists.

This is my code:

`Set-ItemProperty -Path $mypath -Name $myname -Value 0`

The problem with this code is in the Set-ItemProperty class; It creates the DWORD32 value even if it doesn't exist, and I want to change its value only if it exists.

Any solutions?

Comment: You could always try a `Test-Path` on the registry key before trying to set it...

Comment: Yeah, couple actually. You can try `Get-ItemProperty` and/or `Test-Path` with an `if(){}` statement to evaluate against the returned result from one of those cmdlets. Then done

Comment: Glad to hear it; my pleasure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue) returns any success output while ignoring any errors (in PSv4-, use [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty)):

```
if ($null -ne (Get-ItemPropertyValue -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath $mypath -Name $myname)) {
  Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $mypath -Name $myname -Value 0
}
```

Note:

- The above just tests *whether* the registry value exists - it doesn't check its *data* type. For the latter, you could use (the value returned by [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValueKind()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValueKind) is of type [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind)):

  ```
  (Get-Item -LiteralPath $path).GetValueKind($myName) -eq 'Dword'
  ```
- Note that use of [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path) is *not* an option in this case, because it can only test for provider *items* (which map to registry *keys*), not also their *properties* (which map to registry *values*).